# Can someone confirm how Microsoft Excel 2007 internally represents numbers?

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2007

I know the IEEE 754 floating point standard by heart as I had to learn it for an exam. I know exactly how floating point numbers are used and the problems that they can have. I can manually do any operation on the binary representation of floating point numbers.

However, I have not found a single source which unambiguously states that excel uses 64 bit floating point numbers to internally represent every single cell "type" in excel except for text. I have no idea whether some of the types use signed or unsigned integers and some use 64 bit floating point.

I have found literally trillions of articles which 1) describe floating point numbers and then 2) talk about being careful with excel because of floating point numbers. I have not found a single statement saying "all types are 64 bit floating point numbers except text". I have not found a single statement which says "changing the type of a cell only changes its visual representation and not its internal representation, unless you change the type from text to some other type which is not text or you change some other type which is not text to text".

This is literally all I want to know, and it's so simple and axiomatic that I am amazed that I can find trillions of articles and pages which talk around these statements but do not state them directly.

Comment: I think Excel, like most Microsoft products, stores numbers as sequences of ones and zeroes, with older versions using the occasional two now and again.

Comment: your question has been correctly answer twice based on your original question that was a little vague which is why you have two correct answers, one answer on the old XLS format (2003) and the other on the newer XLSX (2007) format.  You just rewrote your question to the point where it is completely different from what you asked and what was answered. You asked specifically about the Excel 2007 file format and how it stores floating point numbers. Default format for 2007 is XLSX so that is what I answered for, other option could have been XLS which codeka answer is for.

Comment: you seem to be asking now about how Excel 2007 represents cell values in MEMORY, where before it seemed clear you where asking how they where represented in file formats. The file formats are well documented, however the reason you have not found what you are looking for is because Microsoft doesn't document that stuff for a reason.

So while the answer would be simple to one of the core Excel team developers at Microsoft, it may not be possible to find it easily outside of that team.

You should find an Excel team members blog and try to send him an e-mail or post with your question.

Comment: @Creepy Gnome - I have not edited my question at all, it remains the same as when I posted it. Your answer was useful, but what I really wanted to know was how it stores the values in memory and whether or not it converts them to other type when mathematical operations are done on them, as some algorithms are unstable when using floating point numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel 2007 supports the OpenXML format which is a ZIP file (.XLSX) containing a bunch of XML files.  There is an SDK to work with the OpenXML format you can get the docs for it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx), and download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AD0B72FB-4A1D-4C52-BDB5-7DD7E816D046&displaylang=en).

Basically numbers are stored as plain text within a  element so if cell A1 has the number 42 and cell A2 has the number 81.56 in the UI, the XML would look like the follow XML fragment:

```
<row r="1" spans="1:2">
    <c r="A1">
        <v>42</v>
    </c>
    <c r="B1">
        <v>81.569999999999993</v>
    </c>
</row>
```

When working with OpenXML I would highly recommend just using the SDK and not going after it on your own.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687869%28v=office.12%29.aspx) has a reference for internal Excel data types.

Answer (score -2):

It stored the numbers as double.