# Basic VBA Questions (Integer)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 6
    Range("A1").Value = x
End Sub
```

This means that you assign `X` as Integer, and you say the x equals to 6.
    And then you put the value x(=6) in cell "A1".

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Double
    x = 6
    Range("A1").Value = x
End Sub
```

But why does the second one work also?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? An integer is still a double.

Comment: An integer isn't a double but a double is an integer.

Comment: @Riley Carney: So, you are saying a double like 3.1 is an integer and an integer like 42 is not a double, right?

Comment: No? Its like a dog is an animal but an animal isn't a dog.

Comment: Because VBA manages some silent type conversions to make your life 'easier'. If you wish to know what type was actually passed add the line debug.print TypeName(Range("A1").value)

Comment: Why do you think it should not work?

Comment: @Riley Carney: Ok, if you look at it like that :-) but you know a rational number is also a real number and a real number can be a rational number or not. For your example it means a dog is an animal but an animal can be a dog or not. Sorry for my English but joking in English is certainly not my strength.

Comment: @RileyCarney - an animal is a dog if it's a dog.

Comment: Yeah but if an animal is a cat it isn't a dog :) @SJR

Comment: @RileyCarney - unless it's a cat-dog hybrid. A cog?

Comment: Well that threw a wrench in my system

Comment: Apologies for dogging you with my facetious comments. I really must stop now before I get barked at by a mod. @RileyCarney

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Type conversions.

---

`Range.Value` is a `Variant`, which is a special data type that stores a pointer to a value, along with a description of the data type: that's how a cell can hold a `Double`, a `String`, a `Boolean`, or an `Error` value.

Anything deeper than that is irrelevant to the question at hand.

`Integer` is a 16-bit signed integer type that can easily fit into a `Double`, which is much larger than 16 bits. If you followed the `.Value` assignment with this:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(Range("A1").Value)
```

You would get `Double` in the debug output.

Somewhere in the implementation of the `Range.Value` property, a validation of the supplied value is performed, and if the value is acceptable, it's stored internally in the appropriate data type. If the value isn't of an acceptable data type, error 1004 is thrown. `Integer` being a fine numeric value, all is good.

The exact same thing happens in the second snippet: `Double` being a fine numeric value, all is good. And since any numeric value taken from a cell is a `Variant/Double`, we can reasonably infer that somewhere in the internal guts of `Range`, numeric values are stored as `Double` - although, that could very well just be an implementation detail of how the *getter* of the `Range.Value` property is implemented.

VBA was designed to work with a specific set of data types, and the type libraries of VBA host applications (e.g. Excel) were designed to accept these data types. Hence, you would have to work pretty hard to give `Range.Value` a value it can't deal with, using VBA code.

But before the value even gets to the `Range.Value` property, an implicit type conversion has aready occurred in the second snippet.

```
Dim x As Integer
x = 6
```

Here `6` is an *integer literal*. When VBA executes the `x = 6` instruction, that `6` already has a data type - and that data type is `Integer`.

```
Dim x As Double
x = 6
```

Here `6` is also an integer literal, but it's assigned to a `Double`, which isn't the same type: an implicit type conversion occurs, and `x` happily takes an `Integer` value - because the conversion is *widening*.

Now consider:

```
Dim x As Double
x = 6#
```

Here `6#` uses a *type hint*. `Debug.Print TypeName(6#)` prints `Double`: that `6#` is a `Double` literal - no type conversion occurs here. But it's ugly.

```
Dim x As Double
x = CDbl(6)
```

Now the widening type conversion is explicit.

When an implicit conversion is *narrowing* instead, and the value can't fit into the needed data type...

```
Dim x As Integer
x = 32768 '<~ that's a Long integer literal: doesn't fit the 16 bits of an Integer
```

...then runtime error 6 ("Overflow") is thrown. Since every VBA numeric data type can safely be converted to a `Double`, every numeric value that can be supplied by VBA code, can be assigned to `Range.Value`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation you put here! It is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Internally Excel does not use an Integer. Cells are one of four types:

- Double precision floating point (all numbers including integers,
  currency, dates times etc)
- String
- Boolean
- Error

Note this means all numbers are doubles.

See these references:

[Data types used by Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/data-types-used-by-excel) - "All worksheet numbers in Excel are stored as doubles"

[Excel VBA internal data format and memory storage](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb20e940-9bf0-4837-9f2f-4c7c753af0a1/excel-vba-internal-data-format-and-memory-storage?forum=excel)

Comment: The "Data types used by Excel" link directly contradicts the statement "Internally Excel does not use an Integer", and the "Excel VBA internal data format and memory storage" link is dubious at best (in that it contains some provably false statements) - it also ignores casting at the level of COM objects (`Range.Value2` is a property that doesn't necessarily represent how Excel stores data internally). I'd go as far as to say that it's simply wrong.

Comment: Excel as an application handles more datatypes than the fundamental four, but when it assigns to a worksheet cell such as in the example above, it silently converts to one of the four. With regards to Value2, there's a reason Excel has Value, Value2 and Text ...

Comment: And you're substantiating this how? If everything *internally* in Excel was stored as a float, you'd get floating point errors all over the place. With regards to `Value2`, `Value`, and `Text`, those are ***interfaces*** - the assumption that they point directly at Excel's internal storage is naïve at best.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2815592/6600940) it says everything is stored as text.

Comment: @Storax The answer in that post refers to how Excel writes out the file as OpenXML, not how it assigns the values.

Comment: @Comintern Excel does regularly produce floating point errors from some people's perspectives, enough for Microsoft to have written a post about it: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/

Comment: @Alan Yes, right. It does not say how numbers are handled in memory.

Comment: @Comintern "And you're substantiating this how?" From the Microsoft documentation referenced above where is says "All worksheet numbers in Excel are stored as doubles". I.E. It will read and store data as the most efficient type, but will convert to a double when assigning to a cell.

Comment: So we should use `Double` rather than `Long`?